# Convergence vs Divergence

Tags: convergence-divergence, summation

I have read different articles on Convergence vs Divergence. How the general formula for the partial sums of the series [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H3vCe.gif) and [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XP4lz.gif) be calculated?

$$s_n=\sum_{i=2}^n \frac1{i^2-1}=\frac34-\frac1{2n}-\frac1{2(n+1)}$$
$$s_n=\sum_{i=1}^n\frac1{3^{i-1}}=\frac32\left(1-\frac1{3^n}\right)$$

Please let me know how?
Thanks
sabbir

Comment: See also: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/638078, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/931829, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/42205.

Answer (score 0):

For the second, this series is geometric, and the formula for finding a partial sum of a geometric series is a(1-r^n)/(1-r) where r is the term being raised to a power of i, and n is the number of terms you evaluate to, and a is the coefficient of the sum, which in this case is 1. So, in the second case, r is 1/3, a is 1, and n is unspecified. With some algebra you can turn (1-1/3^n)/(1-1/3) into the solution they give you. One important step is to make sure i=0, which you can do by changing the exponent from i-1 to just i.